# Indexed events not returning values when decoded

Tags: events, logs, ethers.js, factory

I had asked [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/103752/44794) but I omitted some info as I (wrongly) assumed that the omitted info was not part of my problem.

When you emit an event like so:

`event ChildCreated(address indexed creator, address child, uint length);`

and decode it like so in ethers js

`return ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["address","address","uint256"], log.data);`

You get an error:

> Exception: null: value out of range (argument="value", value=20,
> code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.4.0

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this github thread](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/422) I have been able to find a solution.

The solution lies in that **indexed parameters are not included in the connection.data, but in the connection.topics.**

And from the same github thread they have given [code to decode events with indexed parameters](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/422#issuecomment-462526405).

```
let abi = [
    "event newConnect (string indexed hashedName, string name, bytes32 connectId, string encrypted, address owner)"
];

let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi)

getLogs.then((logs) => {
    logs.forEach((log) => {
        console.log(iface.parseLog(log));
    });
});
```